# Eclipse is crashing when i am pressing ctrl+space

Tags: android, linux, eclipse

I am developing an android application in eclipse with linux mint OS . but when i am pressing ctrl+Space . it crashed. Don't know what is happening. please suggest .

Comment: but why r u pressing Ctrl+space?

Comment: Pressing Ctrl+space for auto completion of code

Comment: Linux mint operating system

Answer (score 1):

Check this bug

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342518

"The issue only occurs when eclipse is configured to use the internal browser. If the browser is changed to firefox it does not crash anymore"

[image]

Comment: I am using Firefox itself , now what should i do ?

Comment: Hello Deniz, when i am clicking on web browser in preferences it crashes automatically. i think here is this problem .

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me like 1 oe 2 years ago.
My problem was a conflict between eclipse and xulrunner of firefox.
You can try to disinstall xulrunner and firefox (if they're installed)
I hope this could help you

Comment: Hello LOrenzo, Were you getting the error log in your eclipse setup floder. every time i am getting a error log page in setup folder when i crashed